# django admin css not loading setup

Tags: python, css, django, admin

When opening Django admin css of page is not loading.it shows simple page with no css.

my setting.py file is set to:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = "C:/Users/AJAY/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/myprograms/mysite/mysite/static/"
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
'C:/Users/AJAY/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/Lib/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/',]
```

my project is in

```
C:/Users/AJAY/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/myprograms/mysite
```

try to solve using

```
 $ python manage.py collectstatic
```

but could not resolved

installation on my machine are

```
Python version :3.6.0
Django version :1.10.6
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be something in the absolute path. Add this to your `settings.py` file (if it's not already there).

```
import os
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

Then, define your `STATIC_ROOT`

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

Do the same for `STATICFILES_DIRS`.

Comment: BASE_DIR is set and I now  saw source code in browser which has link tag set to     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/admin/css/base.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/admin/css/login.css" />

Answer (score 1):

You can check the path to your CSS in the browser console (if it doesn't load it should be a 404 - file not found). With that information you should know if the path is wrong (The path is pointing to a place where no such file exists). Use @Nifled 's settings if the path is wrong.

Another idea is that your TEMPLATES list is wrong, try:

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]
```

And the last idea is that you didn't install Django in your virtualenv but in the system. Activate the virtualenv use `pip list | grep Django` and see if you get an result, if not => you don't have Django installed in the virtual environment.

Comment: browser shows error  SEC7113: CSS was ignored due to mime type mismatch

Comment: now it works fine in firefox but still not working in internet explorer and opera

Comment: do you have something like: <!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'native_church/css/ie8.css' %}" media="screen" /><![endif]-->
??

Answer (score 1):

I added following in my setting.py file and now its working fine:

```
import mimetypes
mimetypes.add_type("text/css", ".css", True)
```